# JQuery place in circle first letter of the name

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create first letter circle of the `name` which is showing in the `Data-Id` it is showing but problem is that function repeating first letter for all?

I want to function should be display first letter based on the each `Data-Id` text?

```js
$('#name').each(function() {
  var str = $('#name').attr('data-id');
  var matches = str.match(/\b(\w)/g);
  var acronym = matches.join('');
  $('.shortname').prepend('<div class="my-circle">' + acronym + '</div>');
});
```

```css
.my-circle {
  content: attr(data-letters);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: plum;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 1em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shortname"></div>
<div id="name" class="name" title="" data-id="Testing New"></div>

<div class="shortname"></div>
<div id="name" class="name" title="" data-id="Hello HI"></div>

<div class="shortname"></div>
<div id="name" class="name" title="" data-id="Hello Testing"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `id="name"` to `class="name"`, and the `.each()` loop use `$(this)` to get the values from the current name, and `.prev()` to get the `.shortname`:

```js
$('.name').each(function() {
  var $name = $(this);
  var str = $name.attr('data-id');
  var matches = str.match(/\b(\w)/g);
  var acronym = matches.join('');
  $name.prev('.shortname').prepend('<div class="my-circle">' + acronym + '</div>');
});
```

```css
.my-circle {
  content: attr(data-letters);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: plum;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 1em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shortname"></div>
<div class="name" class="name" title="" data-id="Testing New"></div>

<div class="shortname"></div>
<div class="name" class="name" title="" data-id="Hello HI"></div>

<div class="shortname"></div>
<div class="name" class="name" title="" data-id="Hello Testing"></div>
```

Comment: Use the comments.

Comment: code is working inside the `.name` div but it is not showing under the `shortname` div???

Comment: Run the snippet and inspect the results. I use `.prev()` to get to the `.shortname` div.